# how can we use a table name stored in a string variable in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

```
string tablename = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()
string id = TextBox1.Text;
adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from '" + tablename + "' where id='" + id + "'", obj.connect());
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

string.Format("select * from {0}  Where id = {1}" , tablename , id)

Comment: adp = new SqlDataAdapter string.Format("select * from {0} Where id = {1}" , tablename , id, obj.connect());

not working  showing  error

Comment: adp = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format("select * from {0} Where id = {1}" , tablename , id), obj.connect());